# how to modify an xml file and add an inner node?

Tags: xml, macos, shell, sh

I have this xml file:

```
<xml>
<segmentrecorddb>

...

</segmentrecorddb>
</xml>
```

I want to write a sh file that will add an inner xml node

meaning the file will be:

```
   <xml>
    <segmentrecorddb>
    <myNoed>
    </myNoed>
    ...

    </segmentrecorddb>
   </xml>
```

how can I delete the first two lines

add the 2 lines and add

**Edit1:**

I have tried:
`➜  Downloads  sed "s/<xml><segmentrecorddb>/<xml><segmentrecorddb><myNode></myNode>/" menyHtml.html > menyHtml.html`

and got:

`sed: 1: "s/<xml><segmentrecorddb ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'm'`

Edit2:

```
<xml>
<segmentrecorddb>

...

</segmentrecorddb>
</xml>
```

I ran

```
sed 's/<segmentrecorddb>/<segmentrecorddb>\n<myNode><\/myNode>/' < menyHtml.html > menyHtml1.html
```

for the input

and got output:

```
  <xml>
    <segmentrecorddb>n<myNode></myNode>

        ...

    </segmentrecorddb>
</xml>
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: You can use the `sed` command to edit streams...  So, now you just need to open a stream and scan until a certain point.  Maybe using `grep`

Comment: i'll check. can you write the syntax you thought of?

Comment: You need to escape the / preceeding myNode, as per my answer below.

Comment: Also, you should not do `> mnyHtml.html` as this can overwrite the input file before it is read. You need to use a different filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell scripts are a poor choice for manipulating XML robustly, as the string processing utilities available for UNIX tend to be line oriented, and XML is not line oriented.

If you produce a solution that implicitly relies on where line breaks exist, for example, you'll find that your solution could break when someone changes how the input XML gets normalised.

You may also need to worry about whether you want to alter *every* instance of `<segmentrecorddb>` or just one.

There are some tools that can help e.g. [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) and [pyxie](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/03/15/feature/index.html). However, if you need to install something else, why not install something that can handle XML properly (e.g. Python)?

That said, the following sed command will do the fix in the most simplistic way:

```
sed 's/<segmentrecorddb>/<segmentrecorddb>\n<myNode><\/myNode>/' < input.xml > output.xml
```

Comment: Did you try my code? I did, using your input, and it worked, and I also ran the code you posted, and it also worked. Is it possible you have already overwritten and truncated your menyHtml.html file?

Comment: Using a different pattern separator instead of `/` for things like this makes it much easier. (e.g. `s,<foo>,</bar>,`)

Comment: @spookylukey you're right. I want to change only first instance. I depend on the `<xml>\n<segmentrecorddb>`

Comment: @spookylukey how would you do it with Python?